# Repair automatic perfume dispenser

Tags: capacitor, motor

I'm a total newbie on electronics. All I'm able to do is just connecting broken cable here and there :p So this might be dumb question, but I hope it' still the right place to ask this question

Now I'm trying to repair my automatic air refreshener dispenser. [image]
It won't spray out the perfume. I opened the case, confirmed that the power is still flowing well because the indicator lamp is still beeping and even the motor is rotating.

[image]

It's just that the motor is too weak to push the perfume sprayer. If I replace the battery to the new ones, it might works for a while (the motor works strong enough to push the perfume sprayer), but after one or a few days, it would get weak again.

So what could be the cause of the problem? Is there any components that I could just replace to easily fix it? the capacitor maybe? or perhaps the motor? or anything else?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For all the time you could spend trying to fix something which was cheap to start with you might as well buy another.

Comment: well, it's just my weekend hobby to hack my household stuff anyway, now I'm interested to learn electronics to hack all those electronic junk in my home, I think this dispenser might be a good easy start :)

Comment: I don't mean that your hobby isn't fun.  I mean that trying to fix something which was built to a ridiculously low price point might not be worth attempting.

Comment: Measure the voltage across the motor while it is spinning.  Compare to the battery voltage.  If motor voltage is similar to battery voltage, look for either a defective motor or a mechanical problem.  If motor voltage is significantly-less than the battery voltage, the motor driver device is damaged.  That would be Q2.  Try putting a short between the middle two pins (between the connectors) and see if the motor has enough torque to operate the device.

Answer (score 2):

When it runs the motor, measure the voltage between collector and emitter of Q2. You can assume it has [this pinout.](http://www.taitroncomponents.com/catalog/Datasheet/MMBT8050.pdf)

If that voltage is less than 1V and most of the voltage appears across the motor you can rule out the electronics (which I think is unlikely anyhow, typically an electronics failure would cause it to run continuously or not at all).

Possible the DC motor commutator or brushes are worn or something else is wrong internally (or the gear chain, especially the early gears) is gummed up (use only a **very** light oil).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will all boil down to poor-quality batteries. If you can get access to a higher-quality battery, or one with a different chemistry, I think you'll see better performance.

Comment: well, I've tried at least 3 different kinds of batteries. standard battery, alkaline battery, and rechargable battery. The alkaline one indeed gave me quite a longer working period (a couple days) rather than the others. But, afterward, the problem persist

Comment: @MustafaKamal Replacing the batteries with a 3V DC power adapter would work if you had a plug near by.

Comment: @MustafaKamal, in that case I can only think that something on that circuit board is malfunctioning and drawing **much** more current than it should draw, possibly by running the motor far too often or by sending continuous power to the motor. If the motor was bad, it would either smoke or not turn at all, and if the electrolytic capacitor was bad it'd show visible signs of leakage or swelling. There just aren't any other reasonable user-replaceable parts on that board...

Answer (score 0):

If it has worked before and has now started chewing through batteries, I suspect the motor or the gears are gunked up and could use cleaning and a bit of oil. If it's new, it could be just a bad design that's not really suited for those small batteries. You could try a wall wart (battery eliminator) or just using bigger batteries with the same voltage (e.g. D cells) so that they last longer.

Comment: I've tried to clean and oil the gear, doesn't help at all... should I open the motor case and clean+oil the motor parts?